# Physical reason for light incoherence

Tags: optics, visible-light, coherence, order-of-magnitude

In my physics notes it is stated that the light phase changes every 10^-8 seconds, hence light from 2 light original light sources. 
I understand how light from incoherent light doesn't allow for diffraction but by what physical mechanism does the light undergo phase changes at that rate?

Comment: That's not a general rule.  The coherence time depends on the source.  Your notes must have a particular source in mind.  Without knowing the type of source, not much can be said (other than guesses).